# How to add an object that belongs to another object in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

What I'm trying to do seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure it out. All I really want is a simple way to add one model to the database that belongs to another model. I know it's confusing wording so I'll illustrate.

I have a User model and an Address model. I have a user defined with an id of 1 and I want to add an address to that user. I can add the Address like this:

```
$a = new App\Address;
$a->user_id = 1;
$a->line_1 = '1234 Something Rd.';
$a->city = 'Fort Worth';
$a->state = 'TX';
...
```

But it would be so much easier if I could just say:

```
$u = App\User::first();
$u->address->create([array of options]); /* Or something */
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. How can I do it?
3. What is this called? Does it have a name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$u = App\User::first();
App\Address::create(['user_id'=>$u->id, etc]);
```

or

```
$address = App\Address::create([options]);
$u->address()->save($address);
```

Do not forget to set Model Address.php like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id','etc'];
```

You cannot call

```
$u->address->create
```

because as User does not yet have a address model, the method will return NULL, so ->create will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [Insert Related Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships):

```
$user = App\User::first();
$address = App\Address::create($attributes);
$user->address()->associate($address);
```

Note that how you do this [depends on the type of relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models).